# How to compare strings date GMT on Embedded

Tags: c, time, embedded

I need to compare two dates in GMT time i need only know whether the first date is greater than the second, not need diff. I working on STM32 and operation must be light and fast.

Should i use some functions from standard libraries (there is some function for this, in time.h i didnt see?) or write my own function to compare this?

There is date format (formats will be always identical):

```
const char[] d1 = "Tuesday, 04-Jun-2019 21:20:59 GMT";
const char[] d2 = "Thursday, 06-Jun-2019 20:14:27 GMT";
bool d1GreaterThanD2 = ...;
```

Thanks for you advice i write function to parse this datetime format to `tm` structure from `time.h` and separate function to compare. If anyone want see this solution is here: https://github.com/galczakit/datetime

Comment: "light and fast" are subjective terms.  You need to specify more specific and testable constraints in terms of resource usage, library usage and processing time, and for the latter the performance of your processor is critical.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact format and speed is important, then write your own would be the quickest as you can take early exits. For example, you could grab the "date-month-year" and compare the year first, if they are the same, you can compare the month, etc. only if all 3 match, do you need to look at the time.

You just set pointers to the date beginning, month beginning, and year beginning. The only tricky part is the month, which you have to convert from ASCII to numbers. The date and year are just character comparisons.

Comment: "early exit" yields the answer in the shortest time but results in variable non-deterministic execution time, which may be undesirable in some applications.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty in tis problem is because the date formats are in string, and not any ordered dataset (For example, date would have been declared as a struct, and it could have fields like month, date, year, time, timezone).
The solution would be two step -

1. Write a function to convert this string to ordered dataset. (The tricky part). Should take many test cases into consideration here, including skipping whitespaces, encoding for timezones, month and day.
   To get the day, create a substring from beginning of the data string to where the first comma appear. Compare it with set of days {"Monday", "Tuesday" ... } (use strstr) to generate the day. Date and time would be having fixed offset if we discard the dayname and comma. It is pretty straighforward from here. Write separate parsers for date and time now. It would be adviseable to gather some test cases first, before writing the parser.
2. Write a function to compare two ordered data set and return true/false depending on whether first date is greater than second or not. (Consider the cases when dates are equal too)

This may not be the fastest implementation, but can reuse some code. The early exit implementation described above is faster than this.